# How to use run_classifer.py,an example of Pytorch implementation of Bert for classification Task?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, classification, pytorch, bert-language-model

How to use the fine-tuned bert pytorch model for classification (CoLa) task?

I do not see the argument `--do_predict`, in `/examples/run_classifier.py`.

However, `--do_predict` exists in the original implementation of the Bert.

The fine-tuned model is getting saving in the BERT_OUTPUT_DIR as `pytorch_model.bin`, but is there a simple way to reuse it through the command line?

Using Pytorch implementation from: https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-pretrained-BERT

The command which I am using to execute the code is:

```
python run_classifier.py \
  --task_name CoLA \
  --do_train \
  --do_eval \
  --do_lower_case \
  --data_dir ./split/ \
  --bert_model bert-base-uncased \
  --max_seq_length 128 \
  --train_batch_size 32 \
  --learning_rate 2e-5 \
  --num_train_epochs 3.0 \
```

Comment: Which library/code are you using? Which version of the library/code? What's the full command that you've tried to run? And what's the error output you see from the command?

Comment: The problem is, I am not able to use the run_classifier.py for prediction. However, the original implementation of the BERT https://github.com/google-research/bert , has a `--do_predict` flag, which can be used for the purpose of prediction on test data-set